# Trying to Envoke SNMP-Get from GWT Project

Tags: java, gwt, snmp

I'm working on a implementing a SNMP into a GWT project. I need to do an SNMP get and display the results in my GWT application. But GWT does not allow this (not supported by run time).

So I was thinking of maybe writing a separate java program to do this for me, and then write a text file which GWT can read from.

So I guess what I'm really asking is, how to I use GWT/Java to call another java program?

Honestly I don't really know what I'm talking about, I'm just a first year student. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the code in the server side of your GWT app - there the entire runtime is supported.

Call the server-side method from the client side using an Asynchronous RPC call.

For more information, see this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) from Google, and this little more in-depth [description](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html), also from GWT's homepage.

Comment: Thanks, I think I almost know what I'm doing now. I did a quick search for RPC and didn't really find anything that I could apply directly. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I added some links to my answer - hope it'll help.